# Flutter State Management - architecture used

Tags: flutter, design-patterns, state-management

I would like to briefly ask something that is perhaps a little strange.
In general, there are several design patterns for developing an app (MVVM, MVC, MVP).
In Flutter there are packages that make state management easier.

- Bloc
- Cubit
- Redux
- MobX
- Riverpod
- flutter_command
- Momentum
- Flyweight
- Flutter Hooks

The question is, can the packages be clearly classified in one of the architecture or is it recommended to implement a certain architecture with the package?
For example, I understood that BLoC follows an MVVM concept, while Momentum uses the MVC pattern. Is that right?
Can someone add to the list for the other packages?

Answer (score 3):

Simply,

No, you can not classify state management mechanisms as a design pattern or architectural pattern. State Management & Architecture are two different things.

Why

Flutter is classified as a declarative framework, which means UI is built again & again based on the current app state ( simply current data/ information). So, Flutter State Management is used to share the app state within the widget tree. That's it.

On the other hand, app architecture is about overall communication among different layers on the app, like how UI talks to controllers, controllers to database,  web service, parses, models &, etc